# Pivot query issue while using the comparison operation

Tags: oracle, pivot

When i try run the below query i'm getting this error

> ORA-00917: missing comma
>   00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 26 Column: 22

**Query:**

```
select * from 
(select 'india',po.team,pa.NAME,pa.userid,me.amount as RN
from
port po,
switch pa,
merchant me
where po.SEQNO=pa.SEQNO
and (pa.SEQNO=me.SEQNO and RN is not null)) 
PIVOT (
count(*) for RN in(RN<1,RN-20.01)
)
```

Comment: `RN<1,RN-20.01` is not syntactically valid as part of the `PIVOT`. What are you trying to achieve (please give an English description of your requirement not something in code) and we might be able to suggest how to solve it but currently there is not enough information to guess your requirement.

Comment: For example we have table A
SN SNAME  SDEPT   PERCENTAGE
1 A  CS1  0.12
2 B  CS1  10.56
3 C  IT1  67.01
4 D  CS1  0.12
5 E  CS1  15.09
I want display the percentage columns as <=1, between 10 to 20 and >20 by using the pivot logic

Comment: you'd better to edit your question with this comment above for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want display the percentage columns as <=1, between 10 to 20 and >20 by using the pivot logic

Use a case statement in your initial sub-query:

```
select *
from   (
  select *
  from   (
    select 'india',
           po.team,
           pa.NAME,
           pa.userid,
           CASE
           WHEN me.amount <= 1              THEN '<1'
           WHEN me.amount BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN '10-20'
           WHEN me.amount > 20              THEN '>20'
           END as RN
    from   port po
           INNER JOIN switch pa
           ON ( po.SEQNO=pa.SEQNO )
           INNER JOIN merchant me
           ON ( pa.SEQNO=me.SEQNO )
  )
  where  RN is not null
) PIVOT (
  count(*) for RN in( '<1', '10-20', '>20' )
);
```

Comment: but this doesn't work : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f01c/15. With a little edition this works : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f01c/31.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the catch - fixed it now.